# Using Mac Terminal commands how would I find the newest built .ipa file in a directory and move it

Tags: macos, file, terminal, find

I'm new to Mac terminal as well as stack overflow (So this is probably a very stupid question). I'm trying to figure out a command that would find our newest .ipa in a specified directory. Then move it to a local folder on my Mac.

I was using: find /Volumes/base directory path/filename -mtime 1 to attempt to find the ipa. It shows 2 files, I only need the newest one and need to move it, any help on the best way to do this is much appreciated.

To add: I'm trying to make this a full script to run every morning and pull exact .ipa the file over every morning. (I do know how to make a bash script and kron just not sure on the commands). So I need it to be able to find the last built .ipa, and pull that IPA over without me manually having to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
cd "<specified directory>" && cp "$(ls -1t *.ipa| head -1)" "<local folder>"
```

You will need double quotes around anything that may could contain spaces, e.g.

```
cd "/some/where with/spaces" && cp "$(ls -1t *.ipa| head -1)" "/some/where/local"
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, I ended up doing it a little different than that, but the way you showed put me on the right path. I ended up doing it like this: cd <base path> ; LATEST_BUILD_DIR=`ls | sort -n -t  _ -k 2| tail -1`; LATEST_IPA_PATH=`find ./$LATEST_BUILD_DIR -name <.IPA Name> -print -quit MY_IPA_DIR=<directory to send to> cp -f $LATEST_IPA_PATH $MY_IPA_DIR